# Android Web View rotation

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to rotate webview in android to portrait mode to my android tv application. But the android:rotation="270" makes a blank space on the top and bottom. When I try the same on my android phone, the problem spaces become the left and right:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
     android:rotate="90"> <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->

     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:rotation="90" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information, like if your using it in activity or fragment, or it is the only view in the the parent layout. 
also did you tried with Constraint Layout.

Comment: it is not the only activity the android tv i am working on does not support orientation change that is why i come up with this solution i also found library in github for rotation but when i did rotation it choped top and bottom and stayed in middle also tried constraint layout